# Why are bash's flow control constructs inconsistent?

Tags: bash

I'm teaching myself bash, and using [*Learning the bash Shell*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do) to do so.

I noticed in the flow control that we define an if/else statement as so:

```
if [ statement_is_true ]; then
    # do stuff here
elif [ some_other_statement]; then
    # other thing
else
    # if all else fails
fi
```

and a case statement as such:

```
case $expr in
    case1 )
        ;;
    case2 )
        ;;
esac
```

but a for loop might be defined as

```
for i in $list;
do
    # something cool with the various $i
done
```

and a while loop as

```
while [ condition ]; do
    # something that loops
done
```

Why is the end of the `for`, `while`, and `until` loops denoted with `done` rather than `rof`, `elihw`, and `litnu`, respectively, like the `if/fi` and `case/esac` construct? (Alternatively, why is it `if/fi` instead of `if/done`?

Comment: Because that's what the original shell designer felt like doing.

Comment: Better to ask Bourne, not SO. Maybe he can remember what he was thinking 35 years ago.

Comment: It's not a decision bash's authors had or have any say in -- bash is compliant with POSIX sh, a standard which was derived from ksh in the late 80s/early 90s, which itself inherited a great deal from Bourne's 70s-era shell. Compatibility is what it is.

Comment: [Supposedly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247709/1014938) Bourne considered that the consistent thing to do would be to use `od` (as the reverse of `do`), but that was already in use (octal dump).

Comment: `done` only makes sense with loops ("go here when the loop is done"). `if/done` makes no sense.

Comment: ...by the way, `for i in $list` is Evil And Wrong, as it's string-splitting and glob-expanding a scalar, which leads to all kinds of unusual / unexpected behaviours when folks aren't expecting those steps (and their oft-unintuitive behaviors). `for i in "${array[@]}"` is the right way to do that, but of course, that means you need an actual array with your list contents.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood, still learning the syntax and appropriate style :)

Comment: ...also, if your bash book is telling you to use `[ ]` instead of `[[ ]]`, I suggest burning it promptly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it mentions both usages but for purposes of the text sticks to single brackets. I guess I haven't gotten good enough to understand why double is preferred, but that's clearly outside the scope of this question

Comment: It should be `do/od` but there was already a program `od` so using that as a keyword would have been problematic.  Hence `do/done`.

Comment: @DangKhoa, `[[ ]]` disables string-splitting and glob expansion, thus allowing you to safely avoid needing to quote your expansions within a test. It also has considerably more functionality -- pattern matching tests, regular expression tests, and more. And yes, it's outside the scope -- that's why this is a comment, not an answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that it's just readability, because `litnu` is much harder to read/pronounce than `esac`. See, for example, [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=tZKCZje8178C&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=case/esac+while+elihw&source=bl&ots=GOUj96WthO&sig=RE0IeizlKK-wvDZlDOoeb4KLU-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VS6NU7W1NdahyAT-4YKwCw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=case%2Fesac%20while%20elihw&f=false), where "`end` scores over `nigeb` for obvious reasons."

`fi` and `esac` are easy to pronounce and distinguish from other code. The `do...done` structure also provides a consistent syntax within *loop constructs*, which is arguably more sensible than consistent syntax across all control flow statements.

Comment: +1 for the link to Stan Kelly-Bootle. RIP.

Comment: `litnu` isn't hard to pronounce at all. "Lit-new", rolls off the tongue exactly as you naturally read it in your head. I'd say `esac` is the harder of the two, just because it doesn't feel as natural to say, but both are real easy.